# Setting the time wait period for Get() in akka-http testkit?

Tags: scala, akka-testkit

I am using the akka-http test suite. I have the following code, where the test "fails" whenever I delay the server response by more than 1 second.

```
"should give default" in {
    Get("/test/") ~> route ~> check {
      responseAs[Array[Byte]] shouldEqual defaultImage
    } 
  }
```

The error message is:

> Request was neither completed nor rejected within 1 second

Is it possible to modify this waiting time, for instance with an implicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own `RouteTestTimeout` implicit to override the timeout, the default definition is:

```
implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout(1.second dilated)
```

[Source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/65a9e0a0f9372d2e2ecb945c8a9dae129a438f77/akka-http-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/RouteTestTimeout.scala)